# Jasmine code throwing error object not defined

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am writing jasmine test code for testing following piece of code

```
  validatePage : function(siteIndex) {
    var errorList = '';
    var siteVal = solution.CommonObjects.theSolution.sites[siteIndex];
  }
```

there is further manipulation on value of siteval

I have written following piece of code

```
describe("order handoff site test suites",function(){
beforeEach(function(){
var solution =
{
 CommonObjects:
 {
  theSolution:
   {
    sites:
    [
     {
      floor:""
     }
    ]
   }
}
```

}
 });

```
var ordrHandoffSites = new orderHandoffSite();
it("expect true to be true",function(){
console.log("AHV55" + typeof(solution.CommonObjects.theSolution.sites    [0].floor));

ordrHandoffSites.validatePage(1); 
})
```

This code is using require.js so ordrHandoffSites is just an object of the file containing code for validatepage
while I am checking console log it shows me a string value but the code is breaking on

```
var siteVal = solution.CommonObjects.theSolution.sites[siteIndex];
```

saying Cannot read property 'floor' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observations:**

- Your `solution` object's scope is limited to your `beforeEach`
  function and hence it is returning the `undefined` error.
- I've mocked the `require.js` & used a dummy object instead of
  `ordrHandoffSites` but it(using require.js) should primarily behave the same. See it in [action here](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/23/)

  ```
  var solution;
  var testObj = {
    validatePage: function(siteIndex) {
      var errorList = '';
      var siteVal = solution.CommonObjects.theSolution.sites[siteIndex];
    }
  };

  describe("order handoff site test suites", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      solution = {
        CommonObjects: {
          theSolution: {
            sites: [{
              floor: ""
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    });
    it("expect true to be true", function() {
      console.log("AHV55==> " + typeof(solution.CommonObjects.theSolution.sites[0].floor));
      testObj.validatePage(1);
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

  });
  ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41261559/ajax-test-code-throwing-error

Comment: Can you please help me with above