# Ajax test code throwing error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jasmine

I am testing a code using jasmine and creating a mock object for ajax method

```
spyOn($,'ajax').and.callFake(function(e){
console.log("is hitting");
})
```

to test the following piece of code

```
$.ajax({
               url: AppManager.defaults.contextPath + "/solutions/mcn/mcn-lookup-list",
               data: {
                    mcnNumber       : mcnNumberData,
                    mcnCustomerName : mcnCustomerNameData
               },
               dataType: "json",
               type: "GET",
               global: false
        })
        .done(function(data) {
               solution.CommonObjects.theSolution.orderHandoff.mcnSearchData = self.filterMCNSearchData(data, resultObj);
               $promise.resolve();
        })
        .fail(function() {
             $promise.reject();
             self.displayErrorPopup('MCN Search Error','There is no MCN associated with MCN Number or MCN Customer Name Entered!!!');
        });
    },
```

It's throwing an error cannot read done of undefined . Do I need to create a spy for that also . Please help with the code to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issues with your code:**

- You are spying it right but you need to send in a `promise` object back via your spy. Basically you need to return something like this ==> `return new $.Deferred().resolve(dummyData).promise();`
- There are multiple ways to create a `deferred object/promise object`. I suggest you to read both [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) & [`Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)
- Also could you explain where your `$promise` is coming from? is this some feature of `require.js`?

Below is one way to fake the ajax calls.

```
var testObj = {
    ajaxFunction: function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
      }).done(function(data){
        consoleLogFunction(data);
      });
    }
};

var consoleLogFunction = function(data){
    console.log("The lengh of array is..=> "+ data.length);
};

describe("ajax test suite", function() {
  it("expect true to be true", function() {
    var dummyData = ["Foo", "Boo"];
    spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake(function(e){
      return new $.Deferred().resolve(dummyData).promise();
    });
    spyOn(window, 'consoleLogFunction').and.callThrough();
    testObj.ajaxFunction();
    expect(window.consoleLogFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(dummyData);
  });
});
```